# How to fix the orientation issue in IOS 7

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

Orientation problem is present across the app. All the views looks fine in portrait mode.
But When orientation changes to landscape mode the subviews are rearranged.

I am using `buttons` and `labels` on the view. How to fix the orientation issue so that view for portrait and landscape looks same?

Comment: How can you have the same view? It's a different shape. Do you mean you don't want the UI to rotate, or you want it to have a similar layout? How are you laying out your subviews at the moment?

Comment: No my issue is when i rotate the device to landscape mode,the Buttons and labels in my view are rearranged

Comment: i am using auto layout only.

Comment: learn autolayout from here.. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Its not that easy to implement as many people think. Learning autolayout will take time but its very useful.

Comment: They are technically in the same position i.e. x,y the issue is that the coordinate space is now much bigger. If your are using auto layout how have you defined their position ? Have you set them to be x away from the top/left/bottom/right ? If so you need to make them relational. i.e. 1/3 from the top etc.... That way it'll maintain when you rotate.

Comment: K any other suggestion to fix this issue.

Comment: few ways to fix this - 1. handle this scenario with auto layout 2. programmatically handle the position of all you UI element on change of orientation.

Comment: You can check this tutorial - http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-iOS--Day-16–Handling-Device-Orientation . There are couple of other available to learn

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `springs and struts` or using `autolayout`.

Please refer these wonderful tutorials for getting a hangout of `autlayout` and its advantage over `springs and struts` :

- [Beginning Auto Layout Tutorial in iOS 7: Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)
- [Beginning Auto Layout Tutorial in iOS 7: Part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50319/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-2)

Feel free to comment below if you have any doubts regarding the same.
Hope this helps! :)